# No eddystone service in Radius beacons?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, eddystone

I am building an android app and I am trying to read the available services of my Radius Networks Radbeacon. I have clicked the beacon so that it comes to connectible mode. The available services are the following:

```
BluetoothGatt: onGetService() - Device=0C:F3:EE:04:2B:57 UUID=00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
BluetoothGatt: onGetService() - Device=0C:F3:EE:04:2B:57 UUID=f0cec428-2ebb-47ab-a753-0ce09e9fe64b
```

..and no Eddystone service (a3c87500-8ed3-4bdf-8a39-a01bebede295) , even though it is transmitting properly **an Eddystone UID frame**.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-configure your beacon to transmit an Eddystone frame type (URL, UID, etc) using the [Radbeacon app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.radbeacon) for android.  By default I believe they are configured to act as iBeacons.

Comment: I mentioned that it is transmitting properly and now I have updating my question to "transmitting properly an Eddystone UID frame". I have enabled Eddystone frame only and I am filtering while scanning all non Eddystone frames. The problem appears when I am trying to find the service so I can edit the properties of the beacon in my own app without using the company's SDK

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **the RadBeacon Dot does not have support the Eddystone configuration service.**

Understand that just because a beacon supports Eddystone frames does not necessarily mean that it supports the Eddystone configuration service.  The Eddystone-UID, URL and TLM frame standards were released many months before the Eddystone config service was released.

The only official way to configure the RadBeacon Dot is with the RadBeacon app for iOS, Android and OSX. These apps do use a proprietary GATT Service to configure the beacon, but there is no public API, and even if you reverse engineer it, it is subject to change with any future firmware release.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was almost certain that it will do, since I saw the Radius Networks under the list of [Full support for Eddystone](https://developers.google.com/beacons/eddystone) and Universal configuration (GATT service) ticked at the following table. Am I missing something @davidgyoung?

Comment: Radius offers several models of beacons.  The Dot model does not have the configuration service.