# No Eddystone service in Jaalee beacons?

Tags: android, service, configuration, beacon, eddystone

As I read in the question below:

[No eddystone service in Radius beacons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39225858/no-eddystone-service-in-radius-beacons)

even though some beacons support Eddystome frames, it does not necessarily mean they support Eddystone Configuration service.
Do you know if this is the case of JAALEE-OFA Beacons? (This beacons manufacturer is actually Ankhmaway and the original name is Ankhmaway-OFA)
Here is an image of the mentioned beacons below:

https://www.jaalee.com/static/images/store_photo/ib001_jaalee02.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this model allows for 100% Eddystone Frame configuration, but only iOS, eBeacon App. I use this and other Jaalee models. The Jaalee Beacons allow simultaneous iBeacon and Eddystone functionality.

Comment: Thanks man. I was really suspecting this. Just wanted to make sure. Anyway I think I came out with an alternative to what I'm trying to implement!